# How can I get past the P1 Grand Prix?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

I have a Level 30 Primeape in Pokemon Ash Gray but I still cant get past the P1 Grand Prix event.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should save the game when you start the first battle. Try useing the smae move or wahtever and beat the first trainer. Then Primeape will begin to obey you. Defeat everyone and handover primape to that guy. Or you can keep him but i suggest not.